# R: swimplot package annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I have a swimmerplot builded with the swimplot package in R and want to annotate every bar with the factor/text from another variable of the data.frame which belongs to the respective id/patient.

I cannot share the data, but here's the piece of code I'm currently working on with the very last line being my failure to annotate (Best.response.1 is the name of the respective text-variable).
"id" is the patient variable and "daysuntildeath" the time variable.

```
plot3 <- swimmer_plot(df=data ,id='id',end='daysuntildeath',
                      width=.85, name_fill="Drug.1", id_order="Drug.1") +
    scale_fill_manual(name="Drug.1", values = c("coral1", "lavenderblush4", "maroon4","springgreen3" , "springgreen4", "yellowgreen", "dodgerblue2"))
##################### adding symbols for censoring #############################
### censoring
plot4 <- plot3 + swimmer_points(df_points=
                      data,id='id',time='daysuntildeath',name_shape =
                      'event',size=2.5,fill='white',col='black')
p4_new = plot4 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.15,0)) + labs(y = "Days until death") +
  geom_text(x = "id", y = "daysuntildeath", aes(label = "Best.response.1"), vjust = -0.2, colour = "black")
```

Edit: It is no option to rename the patient variables/tick marks. The id's must be visible, only adding an annotation would be possible.

Comment: Not having an example dataset is tricky, but I believe `ggplot2` typically expects the variables to **not** be quoted. Maybe try
`p4_new = plot4 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.15,0)) + labs(y = "Days until death") +
  geom_text( aes(x = id, y = daysuntildeath, label = Best.response.1), vjust = -0.2, colour = "black")`

Comment: That works as expected. Furthermore, the best information from your piece of code is that the coordinates are within aes(), whereas I used them outside of aes(). Thank you very much. If you want to post this as an answer,  of course I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the main points:

- In the last line, `geom_text` uses the `x` and `y` arguments within the `aes()` function
- Variable names are typically not quoted in standard `ggplot2`

So the final line of code should read:

```
p4_new = plot4 + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.15,0)) + 
   labs(y = "Days until death") +
   geom_text(aes(x = id, y = daysuntildeath, label = Best.response.1), 
             vjust = -0.2, colour = "black")
```